# Laravel: How to add Relationship in Model when my Foreign keys are in array?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a table where I need to save the ids in array, you can see the items in 
events_who is a foreign keys. Any solution where I can create a Relationship in my Model to get the data from the foreign keys? I tried belongsToMany and it doesn't work. :(

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel. How to get relationships where foreign key is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49048041/3404097)

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. Here you could have just googled your title. And "it doesn't work" tells us nothing.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we are having 2 models: `Event` and `Person`
And a `Person` can participate to multiple `Event`

Based on the mentioned relationships, you need to create a pivot table called `event_person` and define two [`belongsToMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships in both models:

In the `Person` model, the relationship will look like:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'event_person');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel / MySQL (Relational Database) don't really work this way. You should check out [Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in this case.

Example table schema/layout:

```
users
|id|name|password|

events
|id|title|body|

event_user (pivot table)
|event_id|user_id|
```

Usually there won't be an array in a column, you should use tables instead. Besides, normally a foreign key would be a table name(singular) following by _id.